# Image uploading/cropping functionality is not working in tabset in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs.

I want to implement https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/ image upload  functionality in tabs.  When I put html  elements which are required for image upload inside 
`<tabset><tab></tab></tabset>` it doesn't work, but when I put it outside tabset it worked fine, but I want it inside `<tabset><tab></tab></tabset>`.

I am getting this error when I put html code inside `<tabset></tabset>`

```
Error: document.getElementById(...) is null
handleDynamicEditingOfScriptsAndHtml@http://localhost/angularAdmin/js/controllers/userForm.js:190:34
@http://localhost/angularAdmin/js/controllers/userForm.js:189:1
invoke@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:4118:14
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</</<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:8356:11
nodeLinkFn/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:7608:13
forEach@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:347:11
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:7607:11
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6993:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6996:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6996:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6872:30
$ViewDirectiveFill/<.compile/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3866:9
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:8125:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:7637:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6993:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6872:30
updateView@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3800:23
$ViewDirective/directive.compile/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3768:9
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:8125:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:7637:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6993:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6872:30
$ViewDirectiveFill/<.compile/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3866:9invokeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:8125:9nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:7637:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6993:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6872:30
updateView@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3800:23
$ViewDirective/directive.compile/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3768:9
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:8125:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:7637:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6993:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6996:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6872:30
$ViewDirectiveFill/<.compile/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3866:9
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:8125:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:7637:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6993:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:6872:30
updateView@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3800:23
$ViewDirective/directive.compile/</<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3762:11
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:14518:15
transitionTo/$state.transition<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:3169:11
processQueue@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:12984:27
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:13000:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:14200:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:14016:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$evalAsync/<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:14238:15
completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:4842:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost/angularAdmin/vendor/angular/angular.js:5215:7
<div ui-view="" class="fade-in ng-scope">
[1]: https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';


angular.module('app', [
'ngFileUpload',
'toaster',
'LocalStorageModule',
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'ngStorage',
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.load',
'ui.jq',
'ui.validate',
'oc.lazyLoad',
'pascalprecht.translate'
]);
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
var version = '3.0.6';
// Form controller
app.controller('FormProfileCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$compile', '$upload', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $compile, $upload) {
    $scope.usingFlash = FileAPI && FileAPI.upload != null;
    $scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null && (window.FileAPI == null || FileAPI.html5 != false);

    $scope.changeAngularVersion = function () {
        window.location.hash = $scope.angularVersion;
        window.location.reload(true);
    };

    $scope.angularVersion = window.location.hash.length > 1 ? (window.location.hash.indexOf('/') === 1 ?
            window.location.hash.substring(2) : window.location.hash.substring(1)) : '1.2.20';

    $scope.$watch('files', function (files) {
        console.log(files);
        $scope.formUpload = false;
        if (files != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                $scope.errorMsg = null;
                (function (file) {
                    generateThumbAndUpload(file);
                })(files[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    $scope.uploadPic = function (files) {
        $scope.formUpload = true;
        if (files != null) {
            generateThumbAndUpload(files[0])
        }
    }

    function generateThumbAndUpload(file) {
        $scope.errorMsg = null;
        $scope.generateThumb(file);
        if ($scope.howToSend == 1) {
            uploadUsing$upload(file);
        } else if ($scope.howToSend == 2) {
            uploadUsing$http(file);
        } else {
            uploadS3(file);
        }
    }

    $scope.generateThumb = function (file) {
        if (file != null) {
            if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            file.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function uploadUsing$upload(file) {
        file.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload' + $scope.getReqParams(),
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'my-header': 'my-header-value'
            },
            fields: {username: $scope.username},
            file: file,
            fileFormDataName: 'myFile',
        });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        });

        file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
            // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
            file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });

        file.upload.xhr(function (xhr) {
            // xhr.upload.addEventListener('abort', function(){console.log('abort complete')}, false);
        });
    }

    function uploadUsing$http(file) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
            $timeout(function () {
                file.upload = $upload.http({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload' + $scope.getReqParams(),
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': file.type
                    },
                    data: e.target.result
                });

                file.upload.then(function (response) {
                    file.result = response.data;
                }, function (response) {
                    if (response.status > 0)
                        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                });

                file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
                    file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                });
            }, 5000);
        }
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

    function uploadS3(file) {
        file.upload = $upload
                .upload({
                    url: $scope.s3url,
                    method: 'POST',
                    fields: {
                        key: file.name,
                        AWSAccessKeyId: $scope.AWSAccessKeyId,
                        acl: $scope.acl,
                        policy: $scope.policy,
                        signature: $scope.signature,
                        "Content-Type": file.type === null || file.type === '' ? 'application/octet-stream' : file.type,
                        filename: file.name
                    },
                    file: file,
                });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        });

        file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
            file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
        storeS3UploadConfigInLocalStore();
    }

    $scope.generateSignature = function () {
        $http.post('/s3sign?aws-secret-key=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.AWSSecretKey), $scope.jsonPolicy).
                success(function (data) {
                    $scope.policy = data.policy;
                    $scope.signature = data.signature;
                });
    }

    if (localStorage) {
        $scope.s3url = localStorage.getItem("s3url");
        $scope.AWSAccessKeyId = localStorage.getItem("AWSAccessKeyId");
        $scope.acl = localStorage.getItem("acl");
        $scope.success_action_redirect = localStorage.getItem("success_action_redirect");
        $scope.policy = localStorage.getItem("policy");
        $scope.signature = localStorage.getItem("signature");
    }

    $scope.success_action_redirect = $scope.success_action_redirect || window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    $scope.jsonPolicy = $scope.jsonPolicy || '{\n  "expiration": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",\n  "conditions": [\n    {"bucket": "angular-file-upload"},\n    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],\n    {"acl": "private"},\n    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],\n    ["starts-with", "$filename", ""],\n    ["content-length-range", 0, 524288000]\n  ]\n}';
    $scope.acl = $scope.acl || 'private';

    function storeS3UploadConfigInLocalStore() {
        if ($scope.howToSend == 3 && localStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem("s3url", $scope.s3url);
            localStorage.setItem("AWSAccessKeyId", $scope.AWSAccessKeyId);
            localStorage.setItem("acl", $scope.acl);
            localStorage.setItem("success_action_redirect", $scope.success_action_redirect);
            localStorage.setItem("policy", $scope.policy);
            localStorage.setItem("signature", $scope.signature);
        }
    }

    (function handleDynamicEditingOfScriptsAndHtml($scope, $http) {
        $scope.defaultHtml = document.getElementById('editArea').innerHTML.replace(/\t\t\t\t/g, '');

        $scope.editHtml = (localStorage && localStorage.getItem("editHtml" + version)) || $scope.defaultHtml;
        function htmlEdit(update) {
            document.getElementById("editArea").innerHTML = $scope.editHtml;
            $compile(document.getElementById("editArea"))($scope);
            $scope.editHtml && localStorage && localStorage.setItem("editHtml" + version, $scope.editHtml);
            if ($scope.editHtml != $scope.htmlEditor.getValue())
                $scope.htmlEditor.setValue($scope.editHtml);
        }
        $scope.$watch("editHtml", htmlEdit);

        $scope.htmlEditor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('htmlEdit'), {
            lineNumbers: true, indentUnit: 4,
            mode: "htmlmixed"
        });
        $scope.htmlEditor.on('change', function () {
            if ($scope.editHtml != $scope.htmlEditor.getValue()) {
                $scope.editHtml = $scope.htmlEditor.getValue();
                htmlEdit();
            }
        });
    })($scope, $http);

    $scope.confirm = function () {
        return confirm('Are you sure? Your local changes will be lost.');
    }

    $scope.getReqParams = function () {
        return $scope.generateErrorOnServer ? "?errorCode=" + $scope.serverErrorCode +
                "&errorMessage=" + $scope.serverErrorMsg : "";
    }

    angular.element(window).bind("dragover", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    angular.element(window).bind("drop", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

}])
    ;
```

**View**

```
<div class="bg-light lter b-b wrapper-md">
<h1 class="m-n font-thin h3">Edit User</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-md">
<!-- breadcrumb -->
<div>
    <ul class="breadcrumb bg-white b-a">
        <li><a ui-sref="app.dashboard"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="active">Edit User</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- / breadcrumb -->
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="FormProfileCtrl">

        <form name="userForm" class="form-validation">
            <tabset justified="true" class="tab-container">
                <tab heading="Personal Information">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.vName" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.vEmail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.vPhone" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="user.vAddress" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group pull-in clearfix">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label>Enter password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="vPassword" ng-model="vPassword" >   
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label>Confirm password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" required ng-model="confirm_password" ui-validate=" '$value==password' " ui-validate-watch=" 'password' ">
                                <span ng-show='form.confirm_password.$error.validator'>Passwords do not match!</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Company Information">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.vCompanyName"  >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.vCompanyPhone"  >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Designation</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.vDesignation"  >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="user.vCompanyAddress"  ></textarea>
                    </div>

                </tab>
            </tabset>
            <!-- I want  --> 
            <div class="upload-div">
                <div class="upload-buttons">
                    <div id="editArea">
                        <fieldset><legend>Upload right away</legend>
                            <div ng-file-drop ng-file-select ng-model="files" ng-model-rejected="rejFiles"
                                 drag-over-class="{accept:'dragover', reject:'dragover-err', delay:100}" class="drop-box"
                                 ng-multiple="true" allow-dir="true" ng-accept="'image/*,application/pdf'">
                                Drop Images or PDFs<div>or click to select</div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-no-file-drop class="drop-box">File Farg&Drop not supported on your browser</div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul ng-show="rejFiles.length > 0" class="response">
                    <li class="sel-file" ng-repeat="f in rejFiles">
                        Rejected file: {{f.name}} - size: {{f.size}}B - type: {{f.type}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul ng-show="files.length > 0" class="response">
                    <li class="sel-file" ng-repeat="f in files">
                        <img ng-show="f.dataUrl" ng-src="{{f.dataUrl}}" class="thumb">
                        <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">                       
                            <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%">{{f.progress}}%</div>
                        </span>             
                        <button class="button" ng-click="f.upload.abort();
                                                    f.upload.aborted = true" 
                                ng-show="f.upload != null && f.progress < 100 && !f.upload.aborted">Abort</button>
                        {{f.name}} - size: {{f.size}}B - type: {{f.type}}
                        <a ng-show="f.result" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="f.showDetail = !f.showDetail">details</a>
                        <div ng-show="f.showDetail">
                            <br/>
                            <div data-ng-show="f.result.result == null">{{f.result}}</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="item in f.result.result">
                                    <div data-ng-show="item.name">file name: {{item.name}}</div>
                                    <div data-ng-show="item.fieldName">name: {{item.fieldName}}</div>
                                    <div data-ng-show="item.size">size on the serve: {{item.size}}</div>
                                    <div data-ng-show="item.value">value: {{item.value}}</div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div data-ng-show="f.result.requestHeaders" class="reqh">request headers: {{f.result.requestHeaders}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <br/>
                <div class="err" ng-show="errorMsg != null">{{errorMsg}}</div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="user.iUserID">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="postForm(user)">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is anyone there who can answer !?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with ng-file-upload and tabset.  Here is how I solved it.

In my controller, I created a new object:

```
$scope.tab_data = {}
```

and then changed the watch to

```
$scope.$watch 'tab_data.files', ->
    $scope.upload $scope.tab_data.files
```

Lastly, I updated the ng-model in my html tag.

```
<div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="tab_data.files" class="drop-box" ngf-drag-over-class="dragover" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true" ngf-accept="'.jpg,.png,.pdf'" class="drop-box">
     <div ngf-drop-available >Drop Images here</div>
     <div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>
     <div>click to select</div>
 </div>
```

Of course my solution is in coffeescript...sorry if that is an issue but it should be easy for you to convert back to js.